# Ruby: Passing an array to starts_with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, loops

I want to check if my url starts with certain strings to save it on to a database afterwards. The strings are stored in an array and since `starts_with?` accepts multiple values, I want to get all array values in `starts_with?`.

```
array = ["www.example.com/content1", "www.example.com/content2", "www.example.com/content3"]

save_url = url.starts_with?() #here I want to insert all array values, but how?

if save_url #I want to check if save_url is true so my entries are somewhat filtered
DBTable.create(url: url)
```

So my question is how to pass the array values to starts_with? And how to check if save_url is true. I'm not that good at arrays and loops in Ruby so any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the value of `url`? And what kind of check you want to to here? Do you want to check if `url` starts with any of the value in array or you want to check whether url starts with all entries in array?

Comment: url is just an address like www.example.com/content1/test.html and I want to test if the url starts with one of the array values

Comment: FYI, it's `start_with?`, not `starts_with?` It probably should be `starts_with?` though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try putting array with splat operator(`*`) like so:

```
url = 'www.example.com/content1/test.html'# => "www.example.com/content1/test.html"
array = ["www.example.com/content1", "www.example.com/content2", "www.example.com/content3"]
save_url = url.starts_with?(*array) #=> true
```

Comment: to dive deeper and understand how/why this works, check out http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-splat-array-manipulation-destructuring/

Answer (score 4):

You could pass the array of URLs as follows to the **start_with?** method.

```
save_url = url.start_with?(*array)
```

Answer (score 1):

start_with accepts multiple strings as arguments, but not an array of multiple strings I don't think.

Why don't you loop array and call start_with inside the loop;

```
array.each do | valid_url |
  save_url = url.starts_with? valid_url
  return unless save_url
  DBTable.create(url: url)
end
```